# How do we preserve moss and how long does it have after being taken off the rock its on?

Tags: plant-care, moss

I have an art project coming up soon, and they want us to bring our resources to the classroom, how long do i have till the moss can no longer survive and how do I preserve it as long as I can without glycerine.

Comment: Is this an art project where your desired result is living moss as part of the final result? I'm inferring that, but explicitly clarifying that point would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

When the environment is too dry for moss it dries up and goes dormant.  You can keep it looking fresh by spraying it with water.

I have moved moss from dry locations in cracks where it looked dead to a moister location and it perks up quite nicely

Answer (score 3):

As answered ; moss needs moisture. However , it must also have light.

Answer (score 2):

Humidity and surface moisture are vital to moss growth and flourishing. You might have success keeping your mosses happy in a terrarium or other closed (or mostly closed) container. The act of removing mosses from the rocks they are found on isn't always bad for them, but the moisture bit really is key.

Answer (score 0):

Experience based on harvesting a little moss and "planting" it alongside some tomatoes.

About half a month(indirect sunlight, water obtained from the soil) and it starts looking yellowish. But I had not followed any of the advice above so You could probably stretch that a lot.